# Похождення слова кре́денс

Tags: етимологія

СУМ повідомляє що [креденс](http://sum.in.ua/s/Kredens) це буфет, [вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%96)) свідчить що слово креденс це діалектне слово та походить від пол. kredens < нім. Kredenz < італ. credenza < лат. credere — «довіряти». Також можна знайти таку інформацію:
[credere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/credere#Italian) за Італійською етимологією це believe.

І ось, власне, питання: яким чином "вірити" перетворилося на шафу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цікаве питання! У нас слово вважається гуцульським діалектним, а втім воно вживається без діал. маркування в меблевій справі, в англ., італ мовах, також в рос.

Дозволю собі без перекладу навести пояснення з мого джерела:

> Credenza - "an Italian sideboard," 1883, from Italian credenza,
>   literally "belief, credit," from Medieval Latin credentia (see
>   credence).
>
> The same evolution that produced this sense in Italian also worked on
>   the English word credence, which in Middle English also meant "act or
>   process of testing the nature or character of food before serving it
>   as a precaution against poison," a former practice in some royal or
>   noble households. Because of that, it also meant "a side-table or
>   side-board on which the food was placed to be tasted before serving"
>   (mid-15c.); hence, in later use, "a cupboard or cabinet for the
>   display of plate, etc." (1560s). These senses fell away in English,
>   and the modern furniture piece, which begins to be mentioned in
>   domestic interiors from c. 1920, took its name from Italian, perhaps
>   as a more elegant word than homely sideboard.

[etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/credenza)

Отже, креденс і справді має стосунок до довіри. Просто дуже далекий стосунок, років так до шестисот.

Comment: Дякую за etymonline.com! Подивився уважніше на https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/credere#Italian --  *ḱred dʰeh₁- (“to place one's heart, i.e. to trust, believe”), compound phrase of oblique case form of *ḱḗr (“heart”) and *dʰeh₁- (“to put, place, set”)